# How to replace a text string with dollar sign $ in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I am trying to replace a text '../../Something' with '$Something' in all .txt files in current directory.Let me know where I am going wrong?

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i "s/..\/..\/Something/\'\$Something'/g"
```

Error - Variable name must contain alphanumeric character

I also tried with but doesn't work-

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i "s/..\/..\/Something/\\$Something/g"
```

Any suggestions for correct command?

Comment: I think you are missing % before s and try using a comma as the seperator eg: "%s,../../Something,$Something,g"

Comment: I need a proper command that can solve replacement with $.Even separator is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shell is treating the `$` as the start of a variable.

There are two ways you can make it work:

1. Use single quotes, which tells the shell to not perform any variable interpolation (among other things):

   `find . -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i 's/..\/..\/Something/\$Something/g'`
2. Escape the `$` from the shell *and* sed. This requires 3 backslashes (the first one escapes the second backslash, the second escapes the dollar sign once the tring reaches sed, and the third escapes the dollar sign in the shell so it doesn't get treated as a variable):

   `find . -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i s/..\\/..\\/Something/\\\$Something/g`

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the extra backslash given in the second command.

> find . -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i 's/../../Something/\$Something/g'

Comment: It gives error message as- sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 0):

Tested the following and it worked for me. Let me know if this works

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i "s,../../Something,$\Something,g"
```

Comment: It gives output as- Illegal variable name.